# Compiling Mesa 10.3.1 on Windows 7

Tags: python, mesa

I'm having some problems compiling Mesa 10.3.1 on Windows 7 using SCons and GCC under MinGW. I'm using Python 2.7.8 with pywin32 extensions build 219. I have followed the instructions from the official Mesa website - http://www.mesa3d.org/install.html , and I am still getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Mesa\Mesa-10.2.8>scons.py platform=windows build=debug li
bgl-gdi llvm=yes
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for MSVC ...  no
Checking for GCC ...  yes
Checking for Clang ...  no
Mkdir("build\windows-x86-debug")
scons: LLVM environment variable must be specified when building for windows
Checking for X11 (x11 xext xdamage xfixes)... no
Checking for XCB (x11-xcb xcb-glx >= 1.8.1)... no
Checking for XF86VIDMODE (xxf86vm)... no
Checking for DRM (libdrm >= 2.4.38)... no
Checking for DRM_INTEL (libdrm_intel >= 2.4.52)... no
Checking for UDEV (libudev >= 151)... no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
  Compiling src\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.c ...
In file included from include/c11/threads.h:70:0,
                 from src\gallium\auxiliary/os/os_thread.h:43,
                 from src\gallium\drivers/llvmpipe/lp_screen.h:39,
                 from src\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.c:49:
include/c11/threads_win32.h: In function 'thrd_equal':
include/c11/threads_win32.h:546:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Ge
tThreadId' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return GetThreadId(thr0) == GetThreadId(thr1);
     ^
In file included from src\gallium\drivers/llvmpipe/lp_screen.h:40:0,
                 from src\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.c:49:
src\gallium\auxiliary/gallivm/lp_bld.h: At top level:
src\gallium\auxiliary/gallivm/lp_bld.h:49:27: fatal error: llvm-c/Core.h: No suc
h file or directory
 #include <llvm-c/Core.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
  Compiling src\gallium\state_trackers\wgl\stw_context.c ...
scons: *** [build\windows-x86-debug\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.o] Error
 1
In file included from include/c11/threads.h:70:0,
                 from src\gallium\auxiliary/os/os_thread.h:43,
                 from src\gallium\state_trackers\wgl\stw_device.h:33,
                 from src\gallium\state_trackers\wgl\stw_context.c:44:
include/c11/threads_win32.h: In function 'thrd_equal':
include/c11/threads_win32.h:546:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Ge
tThreadId' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return GetThreadId(thr0) == GetThreadId(thr1);
     ^
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Can anybody help me, please?

I'm using the default scons.py file.

Comment: "`llvm=yes`"...Well, did you build/install LLVM?

Comment: @genpfault Sorry for the lack of replies - I've been rather busy adjusting to a new environment and the stress had kinda gotten to me. The answer is, yes, I did install and compile LLVM. I built it under the same system, with the same environment. I also tried installing LLVM from various repos and other places, but I got the same error message every single time.

Comment: Which LLVM version were you trying?  It's been a while since I tried but I seem to recall Mesa didn't/doesn't like to build with LLVMs newer than 3.4.